# How to make a method chain conditional?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, anime.js

I'm using an animation library called anime.js. I need to make conditional an animation of the chain (timeline) basing on some check. For example, this is my timeline:

```
const tl = anime.timeline();
tl
  .add(animation_1)
  .add(animation_2)
  .add(animation_3);
```

and I want the `animation_1` only if the variable `a` is `true`, so I

```
const tl = anime.timeline();
tl
  .add(animation_1) // <== I need an if(a == true) on this animation
  .add(animation_2)
  .add(animation_3);
```

How can do this in general with javascript and specifically in anime.js?

Comment: Hi Fred; this is getting close votes because it is currently phrased in an opinion-based way (e.g. "best possible way/best practice"). Please define objective improvements you are looking for, otherwise this question risks being closed (and just a reminder that best practices are not objective).

Comment: Chains by definition return themselves. You can simply store the latest iteration of it in a variable, then on condition continue chaining.

Answer (score 1):

Do it without chaining, using an if statement:

```
const tl = anime.timeline();

if (a) {
    tl.add(animation_1); 
}

t1.add(animation_2)
  .add(animation_3);
```

Comment: You probably want `t1 = t1.add(animation)` though to keep the original chaining behaviour